# In typescript what does it means to have an object property like this "{ [x: string]: any }"?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, types

```
var x: { id: number, [x: string]: any }; // what does second property means?

x = { id: 1, fullname: "Zia" , 32: "Khan" }; // no errors in VS Code v0.9.1
```

If the second property is of type **Array** and its **index** is of type **string** and the **return value** is of type **any** then how can it accepts **index** is of type **number** and **value** is of type **string**?

TypeScript version: 1.6.2

Visual Studio Code version: 0.9.1

Comment: Can you improve your question to be more specific? It sounds like you're running into a problem with changes that have been made in the Typescript compiler, but until you give some more details about what version of Typescript you're using, and what you're trying to achieve, we won't be able to be much help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's say we have this variable declaration:

```
var x : { 
    id: number, 
    [index: string]: number  // This is not an object property! Note the brackets.
};
```

The meaning of the declaration is: *You can assign to variable **x** an object with numeric property **id** and if you access **x** by an index (i.e. `x["something"]`), the return value **has to a number**.*

So you can write:

```
x.id = 10;    // but not x.id = "Peter";
x["age"] = 20 // but not x["age"] = "old"
```

**And now back to your example:**

```
var x: { id: number, [x: string]: any }; // what does second property means?
x = { id: 1, fullname: "Zia", 32 : "Khan" }; // no errors in VS Code v0.9.1
```

`fullname` is a valid object property here because you defined that `x` can be accessed as an array. Strangely, the `32` index is valid for the same reason (even though I would expect that only string indices would be allowed here).

Comment: thanx,but when i try to write this
x : { id : number, [ x : string ] : string };
VS Code rises an error whats the problem in this line?

Comment: Well, because `id` has to be a number and in JavaScript it is the same to write `x.id` and `x['id']`

Comment: `[x: string]: string` implies that `id.x` has to be a string.

Answer (score 5):

> In typescript what does it means to have an object property like this `{ [x: string]: any }`?

These are called *index signatures*. They are covered in the [TSLang Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures).

The signature `[x: string]: any` basically is saying that the type of any index access using a string is `any`.

Comment: my question is as an object property, what it can do ? how we assign it values.